# What means sym prefix before functions name in radare2

Tags: radare2

What means sym prefix in disassembly? For examle, `sym.main`?

Comment: RTFM ! wx 90 @@ sym.*  Writes a nop on every symbol (https://github.com/pwntester/cheatsheets/blob/master/radare2.md)

Comment: Ok, wx 90 @@ sym.* writes a nop on every symbol. But what means sym? Acronym or what?

Comment: Sym ==> symbol ! RTFM again.

Comment: `What means sym prefix` It means you need to understand file formats before you try to disassemble them.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by users in comments `sym` stands for `symbol`.

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol)

> A debug symbol is information that expresses which
>   programming-language constructs generated a specific piece of machine
>   code in a given executable module. Sometimes the symbolic information
>   is compiled together with the module's binary file, or distributed in
>   a separate file, or simply discarded during the compilation and/or
>   linking. This information enables a person using a symbolic debugger
>   to gain additional information about the binary, such as the names of
>   variables and ***routines*** from the original source code. This information
>   can be extremely helpful while trying to investigate and fix a
>   crashing application or any other fault.

As previously stated, a *symbol* may be used to referer to a specific address in the binary (i.e. `sym.main` => `main function`).

Answer (score 2):

Here are symbol prefixes with examples, as output by the Radare2 command "axj" from C:\Windows\system32\gdi32.dll:

- sym.imp.* : "sym.imp.KERNEL32.dll_UnhandledExceptionFilter"
- sub.* : "sub.KERNEL32.dll_RtlCaptureContext_614+410" or "sym.imp.ole32.dll_ReleaseStgMedium+56" (Note the library name in upper- or lowercase)
- fcn.* : "fcn.18000587c+41"
- str.* : "str.._AUIDropTarget+584" or "str.PyShellExt::GetArguments___failed_to_lock_CF_HDROP_hGlobal+124" or "str.memset" (One or two dots)
- section.* : "section..data+16"
- switch.* : "switch.0x180004860"
- case.* : "case.default.0x180004820"
- resource.* : "resource.1"

The only explanation I could find is:

["Flags generally have a prefix in their name, such as str., sym., sub., fcn."](https://monosource.gitbooks.io/radare2-explorations/content/intro/navigation.html)

[Those names are called ‘flags’. Flags can be grouped into ‘flag spaces’](https://www.megabeets.net/a-journey-into-radare-2-part-1/).

As suggested, "fs" command displays:

```
[0x180005218]> fs
0  247 * strings
1    5 * symbols
2    8 * sections
3    0 * segments
4   79 * relocs
5   79 * imports
6    2 * resources
7  104 * functions
```

More information about flags and flagspaces here:
[Radare2, basic commands, flags](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/basic_commands/flags.html)